# concatenate additional text to string variable in pl/pgsql

Tags: postgresql, plsql, concatenation, dynamic-sql

I am using pl/pgsql and I am trying to do somehting like `myvar+="additional text"`

This is what I do

```
mywhere := 'dyn_tab2.id=$1';
IF fk IS NOT NULL
THEN
mywhere := mywhere || "AND dyn_tab2.fk_id=$2";
END IF;
```

So, I want the final `mywhere` to be `dyn_tab2.id=$1 AND dyn_tab2.fk_id=$2`, but I get the following error

```
ERROR:  column "AND dyn_tab2.fk_id=$2" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT mywhere || "AND dyn_tab2.fk_id=$2"
                          ^
QUERY:  SELECT mywhere || "AND dyn_tab2.fk_id=$2"
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function __aa(integer,integer) line 12 at assignment
SQL state: 42703
```

How can I concatenate additional text to an already existing string variable ?

Thank you

Comment: Use single-quotes for strings, not double-quotes.

Comment: @Nicarus Yeap, is was that simple. God, I am an idiot. Thanks for the answer. You can answer properly, so I can vote you as the best answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must use single-quotes around your strings and not double-quotes, like so:

`mywhere := mywhere || 'AND dyn_tab2.fk_id=$2';`

Double-quotes are used to indicate an object, like a column.